# Limiting the number of variables that one can use in twiki

Tags: security, controls, wiki, twiki

Can I somehow limit the number of variables that a user can have access to somehow. Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: why do you need this, and what kind of 'variables' are we talking about?

Comment: i am talking variables which allow them to change the read/write permissions of the other users.. because our site will be institution wide... say changing the view permissions can prove to be really dangerous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer to the problem.
Read the [discussion](http://foswiki.org/Development/PermissionsChange) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Main.TWikiPreferences` and your `WebPreferences` allow you to set a variable called `FINALPREFERENCES`. You can set this to a list of variables. These variables are locked. If, for example, the `FINALPREFERENCES` in your `TWikiPreferences` mention the variable `DOCWEB`, this variable cannot be modified in any `WebPreferences`, topics or user preferences.

You can read more about [preferences](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiVariables#Preferences_Variables) and [access control](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiAccessControl) in TWiki (the same topics should be present in your local TWiki installation).

Note: I'm a [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org/) admin, I do not use TWiki anymore. While the mechanism described is the same in Foswiki and TWiki, variables and topics might have slightly different names and I am not 100% sure if I have used the correct TWiki names in the above. Nevertheless, you should be abled fo find such details when you follow the links provided.